# nonhomogeneous Poisson process elementary question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $N_t$ is a nonhomogeneous Poisson process. Find $P(N_{t_2}=n|N_{t_1}=m)$ where $t_1<t_2$ and $n \geq m$. My solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(N_{t_2}=n\mid N_{t_1}=m)&=&\frac{P(N_{t_2}=n,N_{t_1}=m)}{P(N_{t_1}=m)}\\
&=&\frac{P(N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=n-m,N_{t_1}=m)}{P(N_{t_1}=m)}\\
&=&\frac{P(N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=n-m)P(N_{t_1}=m)}{P(N_{t_1}=m)}\\
&=&P(N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=n-m)\\
&=&e^{-(\Lambda(t_2)-\Lambda(t_1))}\frac{(\Lambda(t_2)-\Lambda(t_1))^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}\\
\end{eqnarray}
is it correct? Thank you

Comment: Looks totally correct.